# Jackson - ReadValue fails

Tags: java, json, jackson

UPDATE! Fixed, there was a missed public statement on prices attribute that was the reason this error occurred.

I am trying out Jackson for converting between .json files and objects. However, I keep receiving this error `"UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "Prices" (class imp.JsonDTO), not marked as ignorable (one known property: "Ticker"]"` .
I am trying to convert a json file that looks like this:

```
{
  "Ticker": "AAPL",
  "Prices": [
    {
      "Date": "1986-01-02T00:00:00",
      "Value": 22.25,
      "Action": "Sell"
    },
    {
      "Date": "1986-01-03T00:00:00",
      "Value": 22.38,
      "Action": "Buy"
    },
    {
      "Date": "1986-01-06T00:00:00",
      "Value": 22.38,
      "Action": "Sell"
    }
    ]
}
```

I am converting like this:

```
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    File file = new File("INTC.json");
    JsonDTO dto = mapper.readValue(file, JsonDTO.class);
```

DTO's that I am using:

```
public class JsonDTO {  
public String Ticker;
List<PriceDTO> Prices = new ArrayList<PriceDTO>();
}
```

and..

```
public class PriceDTO {
    public String Date;
    public double Value;
    public String Action;
}
```

Tried a few different ways for "Prices" but seem unable to get it right.Thanks for help :)

Comment: `Prices` should be public, or have a setter. Btw you should reconsider your variables naming system.

Comment: Thanks! That fixed the issue :)